# BeautifulSoup only returns what is inside the head tag

Tags: python, url, web-crawler, beautifulsoup

I'm working with BeautifulSoup and either came up with a bug or an error on my part. In my example, I crawl a sub-section site of NY Times...

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
website = "http://www.nytimes.com/pages/politics/index.html"
data = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(website).read())
print data
```

When I run the code, I'm returned with the head tag and what is inside it. However, it does not grab what is inside the body tags. If I were to change the website url to `http://www.nytimes.com` then BS returns the full page source. What's going on here and why am I not getting the body tags when I crawl `http://www.nytimes.com/pages/politics/index.html`?

Comment: Could not reproduce. When I run this code it gets the full page, not just the `head` tag.

Comment: Hmmm... the code in the question is verbatim to what's in my file. I will say it also grabbed the `html` tags. It's just acting like the `body` tags do not exist.

Comment: What version of BeautifulSoup are you using? And to be clear, if you print `data.body` after the code above (and only the code above), it prints `None`? (For me it prints the contents of the `body` tag)

Comment: I have BS4, and yes it prints `None`.

Comment: Interesting... the old version doesn't have that error, so this looks like a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug in BeautifulSoup. The Problem is actually in the fact that bs4 uses the inbuilt HTMLParser which is not very lenient with malformed HTML and as the [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://tinyurl.com/azgex7z) shows the HTML is indeed malformed and had few unenclosed, stray and misplaced TAGS causing HTMLParser and subsequently BeautifulSoup to stop parsing abruptly.

This problem has been explained in the following bug filed against BeautifulSoup

[BS4 stops parsing after malformed tag](https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/972524)